# Google Authenticator not verifying for MtGox bankruptcy site

Tags: mtgox, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to file a claim on the mtgox.com site for rehabilitation and part of that requires setting up two-factor authentication via Google Authenticator, but when I enter the 6-digit code it says "code does not match" and refuses to allow me to proceed. I tried calling the service number, but it just hangs up on me. What should I do?

Comment: Is the time on the device generating the code correct?

Comment: @RaghavSood I have an iPhone and the main clock on the iPhone is the correct local time where I am.